# Why doesn't the .replace method work in Google Apps Script? I need to remove spaces from an array of strings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Apologies in advance for the noob question: I simply want to parse through an array of strings, remove the spaces, and put the new space-less strings in a column in another sheet. I know that /\s is for spaces and /g is for the whole string. I tried this but I get the message "Cannot find function replace in object..." Why does .replace not work in Google Script?

```
  data2=[];
  for (var y = 0; y <= max; y++) {
    var prodName= data[y];
    var handle=prodName.replace(/\s+/g,'');
    data2.push(handle);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2,2,max).setValue(data2);
```

Is there any other method for removing spaces from strings in an array that would be better?

Comment: Are you sure that all elements of the array are of type String?, try: `if (typeof prodName === 'string') handle = prodName.replace(/\s/g, '');`

Comment: yes they're all strings. It appear to me to be a problem with the .replace function according to the error message I receive. Maybe I need to import a library for it work?

Comment: Without knowing what `data[y]` is, this question is unanswerable, except to say that the object isn't a String.

Comment: [["DR- Line Arrow"], ["DR- Line Cookie- Non Direction"], ["DR- Finger Spool 100' SS"], ["DR- Finger Spool 125'"], ["DR- Finger Spool 50'"], ["DR- Finger Spool 50'"], ["DR- Line #21 White"], ["DR- P...
This is what "data" is in the debug window. This is an array of strings right?

Comment: The error I get is ": Cannot find function replace in object DR- Line Arrow" which leads me to believe that the function replace is unavailable. It appears to correctly be attempting to apply replace to the first string in the array "data," but is unable to find the function.

Comment: ["DR- Line Arrow"] if I'm reading the debug information correctly. It's an array of strings that was pulled from another sheet using the getRange and getValues functions

Comment: Try: `var prodName = data[0][0];`.

Comment: My hero! That totally worked, now I wish I understood why :P Thank you so much

Comment: It works because `data[0][0]` IS a string, while `data[0]` was an array. You originally had an array of arrays of strings.

Comment: Yourself published the answer: `[["DR- Line Arrow"], ["DR- Line Cookie- Non Direction"], ["DR- Finger Spool 100' SS"], ["DR- Finger Spool 125'"], ["DR- Finger Spool 50'"], ["DR- Finger Spool 50'"], ["DR- Line #21 White"], ["DR- P... `.

Comment: Thanks guys, you're awesome

Answer (score 0):

Try the function below. I forced prodName to a string. I also changed data2.push(handle) to data2.push([handle]) to make it a 2D array (needed to set values). And changed sheet.getValues to correct range and changed setValue to setValues. The below function works for me.

```
function testit(){
sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
var data2=[];
var data=[["DR- Line Arrow"], ["DR- Line Cookie- Non Direction"], ["DR-   Finger Spool 100' SS"], ["DR- Finger Spool 125'"], ["DR- Finger Spool 50'"], ["DR- Finger Spool 50'"], ["DR- Line #21 White"]]
  for (var y = 0; y <= data.length-1; y++) {
  var prodName= data[y];
  var test = prodName.toString()
  var handle=test.replace(/\s+/g,'');
  data2.push([handle]);
  }
var r = sheet.getRange(2,2,data2.length,1)
r.setValues(data2);
}
```